# Copy SQL Server database in code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two SQL Server connection strings, CX and CY.

What I need to do is

1. Ensure CY has no tables in it.
2. Backup the database CX.
3. Restore it to CY.

Haven't found what I am looking for yet.  I don't want a tool to do this, I need to do it in C# code at runtime because the action of adding a new Client needs to copy a master DB to an empty DB.  I can't use a pre-made script because I need to also copy data, and the master DB could have been updated only seconds before the new client was added.

===UPDATE===

I am using Smo.Backup and Smo.Restore.  When I try to restore I get:

ERROR 3154 The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing database.

Can anyone tell me how to get around this?  Other than that I have a working solution!

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Hi Pete, to your update (understanding that you probably addressed this over a month ago:) ) - are you setting the "Restore.ReplaceDatabase" property to True?

Answer (score 8):

A Solution with Database Backup:

1) Ensure no tables

```
select COUNT(*) from sys.sysobjects where xtype = 'U'
```

2) Backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyFirstDatabase TO DISK= @path WITH FORMAT
```

3) Restore

```
RESTORE DATABASE MySecondDatabase   FROM DISK = @path WITH REPLACE
```

See SQL Books Online for more Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO).  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx.  Information specifically on backing up a database is at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your desire to do this in C# code, but I really think just calling a command line tool to do it for you would be easiest.

That said, [this guy](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2004/08/26/220735.aspx) has a script that looks like it would do what you want.  You could probably wrap that up in a SPROC and call it easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into the

```
SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup  class
```

see [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx)  also, this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/7690214d-4cba-4757-9956-05f0ca408db5) could be a reference, depending on your specific needs.

Comment: I'm trying this approach but unable to restore the backup to a new DB.  Any ideas?  (Check out the updated question text).

Comment: The error message shown seems to indicate that the ReplaceDatabase property of the [SqlServer.Management.Smo.]Restore object is not set to True; CY doesn't match the database defined in the backup, and therefore SQL sends this message (better that way... one may have typo-ed the dbname) By explicitly setting ReplaceDatabase on tells SQL that it is ok to overwrite the existing db.

Comment: BTW, I assumed this was in the context of a 'fancier' utility that would automate this backup process (with progress bars, more specific error handling etc.)  For a simpler approach, T-SQL exposes much of the backup/restore feature, as shown in Arthur's response.  You can call such TSQL statements, by way of ADO or other and avoid dealing with SMO's object model.