# c# easy way to create new db when new customer is added

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

what can be a easy way to create new db when we create new customer record?

Scenario:

1. I have list of customers [may be upto 500 customers] in master database
2. Whenever I add new customer in my application, I would like to create new separate database to each client [just to separate respective clients' data entirely from each other]
3. Application will connect to master database and respective client db as per login credential.

   - No of customers may be upto 500,
   - I am planning to add only 50 dbs per server instance, after that again will be adding to next server instance

Options I have selected:

1. Use Code first approach of ef6.0 to create and seed primary data of each client when new client is added
2. Use Custom ["Create database script"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql) and import seed data from custom script.sql file

Comment: How many customers are you anticipating?

Comment: upto 500 customers

Comment: You may want to test how your SQL Server performs if it has 500 databases on it. And you may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844479/multiple-databases-vs-single-database-with-logically-partitioned-data of use.

Comment: of course i will be seperating 50 dbs per instance of sql server.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework)

Comment: @SteveGreene your solution looks much good, wondering whether it is available in EF6 also or not...

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of articles out there like [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-multitenancy). Just search "multi tenant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copy SQL Server database in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477169/copy-sql-server-database-in-code) would be a reasonable option for backing up and restoring an existing 'vanilla' (i.e. with no customer data in it) database.

> Of course you only need to backup once - you just restore for each new customer.

Comment: seems good and easy option... trying it right now... btw i miss creating blank db to new customer before restoring it with backup of existing db

Comment: Excellent - I am glad I could be of assistance!